# Login Authentication problem with React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am facing an issue with the sign in authentication page. The app wont let me input any username. Instead, it generates a prompt that says "Enter user name and password": [image: prompt]

```html
***LoginScreen.js***

import React from 'react'
import{View,Text,StyleSheet,TextInput,TouchableOpacity}from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'

class LoginScreen extends React.Component{

    state={
      username:"",
      password:"",
      loading:false
    }
     onChangeHandle(state,value){
       this.setState({
           [state]:value
       })
     }
     dologin(){
     const{username,password}=this.state
     if(username && password){
        const req={
            "email":username,
            "password":password
        }
        this.setState({
            loading:true
        })
        axios.post("https://reqres.in/api/login",req)
        .then(
            res=>{
               this.setState({
                   loading:false,
               })
               AsyncStorage.setItem("token",res.data.token)
               .then(
                   res=>{
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("App")
                    alert("Login Successful")
                   }
               )
               
            },
            err=>{
                this.setState({
                    loading:false
                })
                alert("User Name Password is wrong")
            }
        )
        }
     
     else{
         alert("Enter Username and password")
     }
    }
     
    render(){
        const{username,password,loading}=this.state
        return(
            <View
            style={styles.container}
            >
                <View
                style={styles.formWrapper}
                >
                    <Text
                    style={styles.welcomeText}
                    >Welcome Back User            
                    </Text>
                    <View
                    style={styles.formRow}
                    >
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                       placeholder="Enter username"
                       placeholderTextColor="#333"
                       value={username}
                       onChangeText={(value)=>this.dologin()}
                       disabled={loading}
                      />
                      </View>
                      <View
                      style={styles.formRow}
                      >
                      <TextInput
                      style={styles.textInput}
                       placeholder="Enter password"
                       placeholderTextColor="#333"
                       secureTextEntry={true}
                       value={password}
                       onChangeText={(value)=>this.dologin('password',value)}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={0.8}
                    style={{
                        ...styles.signinBtn,
                        backgroundColor:loading ? "#ddd" :"blue"
                    }}
                    onPress={()=>this.dologin()}
                    disabled={loading}
                    >
                    <Text
                    style={styles.signinText}
                        >
                            {loading ? "Loading...":"SignIn"}
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
export default LoginScreen;

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        height:'100%',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:"center"
    },
    formWrapper:{
        width:'80%',
        marginBottom:10
    },
    formRow:{ 
    marginBottom:10
    },
    textInput:{
     backgroundColor:'#ddd',
     height:40,
     paddingHorizontal:10,
     color:'#333'
    },
   welcomeText:{
       textAlign:'center',
       marginBottom:30,
       fontSize:24,
       fontWeight:"bold"
   },
   signinBtn:{
    paddingVertical:10
   },
   signinText:{
   textAlign:"center",
   color:'#fff',
   fontSize:18,
   fontWeight:"bold"

   }
})
```

I cant seem to find the root cause of the error. I have read the code to debug many times. Its been quite a few hours now and it is actually pretty frustrating.

Comment: I suggest you to separate out the methods for onChangeText and onPress. Looks like using the same function for all of these is creating issues for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling method do login whenever value gets changed of the input value you need to call this method only once while clicking on the button, and to take the values of the input box you need to use this.setState method attaching and sample code that will help you.

```
  <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                       placeholder="Enter username"
                       placeholderTextColor="#333"
                       value={username}
                       **`onChangeText={value=>this.setState({username:value })}`**
                       disabled={loading}
                      />
                      </View>
                      <View
                      style={styles.formRow}
                      >
                      <TextInput
                      style={styles.textInput}
                       placeholder="Enter password"
                       placeholderTextColor="#333"
                       secureTextEntry={true}
                       value={password}
                       **onChangeText={value=>this.setState({password:value})}**
                      />
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={0.8}
                    style={{
                        ...styles.signinBtn,
                        backgroundColor:loading ? "#ddd" :"blue"
                    }}
                    onPress={()=>this.dologin()}
                    disabled={loading}
                    >
```

Comment: Thankyou so much this thing was giving me a headache for quite a few hours now